# Update, copy file from php script ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, chmod, freeradius, chown

I have freeradius management system which is developed by php language 
I want to copy file1 inside freeradius folder to the file2 inside same folder 
but I can not do that even if I set permission to www-data 
I used this code to copy file

```
exec('cp /etc/freeradius/modules/file1  /etc/freeradius/modules/file2');
```

the result of `ls -l /etc/freeradius/modules/file1`  is

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 www-data freerad 0 Dec 15 10:28 /etc/freeradius/modules/file1
```

where is my wrong and how can I do that?

Comment: What are the access rights of www-data to the containing directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the wrong is that I don't have permission to access freeradius folder from www-data user so when I set freeradius owner by www-data the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what is wrong with your code, but you can try this:
    copy('/etc/freeradius/modules/file1', '/etc/freeradius/modules/file2');